# Could a lens be used to melt sand into glass

Tags: optics

Could I melt sand, like that inside a sand dune, into glass using a focused lens?

What factors would affect a lens melting sand?

I was thinking you could use a lens to melt sand, to gather sand into a mold, and to use that for building products in areas surrounding deserts.  Is this practical?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't get a lens large enough to focus enough light to melt the sand.
But you could use mirrors. With some modifications to raise the temperature from [500°C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_power_tower#Design), you need about 1300°C to melt sand.

Comment: I like the source for the 500 C but would comment that it's probably quite a bit lower than the system could get if the goal was to reach max temperature.  The collector is being actively cooled as steam flows through it to be heated. Shut off that flow and you could probably fry the collector in seconds ($10 MW$ going into a few $m^2$!).

Comment: So if I made a mirror ring focus energy onto a metal form with sand inside, if I stop steam from flowing out of the area I would attain greater than 1300 degrees for glass ?

Comment: In an article I saw the temperature that could be reached, but I forget what it was. I just remember that if there was not any coolant, it would melt.